# Looping through posts displaying 4 at a time

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, cycle

I am trying to make a slider cycle through the custom posts in Wordpress, displaying 4 at a time.
I would like it to cycle through the posts and just loop back to the first one when it has reached the last post.
My code is:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="item active">
             <div class="row">
               <?php 
      $args = array(
     'posts_per_page' => '4',
     'post_type' => 'dogs',
      );

      $myDogs = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
       <?php while ( $myDogs->have_posts() ) : $myDogs->the_post();?>
                 <div id="sl-cont" class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                       <div class="well">
                              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('slider-size'); ?></a>
                             <div class="dog-caption">
                               <p><span class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></span><br/>
                               <?php the_excerpt(); ?><br/>
                               <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read more >> </a></p>
                             </div>
                       </div><!--end of well-->

                 </div><!--end of container-->
                  <?php endwhile;
                  wp_reset_postdata();?>

             </div>
         <!--/row-->
     </div>
     <!--/item-->

     <div class="item">
             <div class="row">
               <?php 
      $args = array(
     'posts_per_page' => '4',
     'post_type' => 'dogs',
     'offset' => 1
      );

      $myDogs = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
       <?php while ( $myDogs->have_posts() ) : $myDogs->the_post();?>
                 <div id="sl-cont" class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                       <div class="well">
                              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('slider-size'); ?></a>
                             <div class="dog-caption">
                               <p><span class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></span><br/>
                               <?php the_excerpt(); ?><br/>
                               <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read more >> </a></p>
                             </div>
                       </div><!--end of well-->

                 </div><!--end of container-->
                  <?php endwhile;
                  wp_reset_postdata();?>

             </div>
         <!--/row-->
     </div>
     <!--/item-->

  </div>  <!--/carousel-inner-->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/left-paw.png"> </a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/right-paw.png"></a>
```

`

Can anyone help?

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: When it goes through the cycle say i have 6 posts i would like it to repeat back to the 1st post post 1- post 2-post 3- post 4-post 5-post 6-post 1-2-3-4-5 etc. at the moment it doesn't do that. Simply would like it to display the posts just repeated if the i add more posts later.

Comment: i understand, but what happens right now? nothing? not showing anything?

Comment: Sorry, It displays all the posts correctly when you cycle through the the controls it would go to the next set of posts but if there are say 6 posts the first slide would show 4 and then the next slider would only show 2, leaving white space where i'd like it to loop back round.

Comment: well the problem is that you are only looping as long as there are posts with `while` - you should load all posts, save it to an array, do a foreach over the array and always create 4 slides per view in the carousel.

Comment: How would I achieve implement this? Should I remove the while loop?